# AngularJS + IE + iframe paste in textarea = crash madness

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, angularjs, embed

This is crazy.  I'm am in development on this site for a client where users can paste the embed code from youtube into a text area on the screen.  They click "add", and the code gets put in a property of an object, which in turn gets pushed onto the end of an array.  You are then presented with your "list" of videos, and there is a "new" button to add more.  As soon as you click the "New" button on the page to add a 2nd, IE freezes up.  I have tried IE 9 - it does it almost 100% of the time - once it worked, but I had added other stuff first.
IE10 seems to work fine but I could have sworn I was having the issue there before - but tonight, it does seem fine.
**Update:** Just tested IE8 on Windows XP - no issues.

After much debugging I believe I've actually come to the insane conclusion that if the iframe is 560 pixels or wider, it crashes... if you change the size to say 550, no problem... all this while the iframe in question is NOT actually on the page (you can preview it, but it is not shown or even injected into the page by default.)

Some other notes:
I tried inserting a simple iframe, just a src attribute - no issues.
I tried inserting a BUNCH of html - no issues.
I tried inserting INVALID html - no issues.
I took YouTube's code, changed the URL - HAD the issue issue.
I tried re-typing YouTube's code by hand - HAD the issue issue (was hoping for some odd encoding or something when I tried this.)

This site is getting close to done, so any help on this would be much appreciated!

For your convenience I've setup a site to actually see this on:

http://cars.thomporter.com

You will need to login first:
Username: test@testers.com
Password: test1234

Then proceed to /submit or click "Sell your Car" in the nav and click "List it Fast" on the subsequent page.

You can immediately go to the "YouTube Videos" tab and try that - you don't have to work your way across the tabs...

Here's some code (CoffeeScript & Jade - JavaScript & HTML can be seen on the site...)

early in the controller I initialize the video list to an empty array:

```
$scope.formData = 
    videos: []
```

Here's the method that is called when a new video is submitted (edited down slightly)

```
$scope.addVideo = ->
    v = {
        id: 0
        code: $scope.new_video.code
        listing_id: $scope.listing_id
    }
    $scope.formData.videos.push v 
    $scope.new_video.adding = false # hides the "add" form.

    $scope.new_video.code = ''
```

The HTML that renders the videos tab in the listing editor (I'm using AngularUI Bootstrap for this)

```
pane(heading="YouTube Videos", active="panes.videoActive")
    div(ng-show="new_video.adding || !formData.videos.length")
        h4 Add Video
        p Paste the embed code from YouTube to add video:
        textarea(ng-model="new_video.code")
        br
        a.btn.btn-primary(ng-click="addVideo()") <i class="icon-save"></i> Add Video
        |  
        a.btn.btn-danger(ng-click="new_video.adding = false;new_video.code=''") <i class="icon-trash"></i> Cancel

    div(ng-show="!new_video.adding && formData.videos.length")
        .row-fluid
            .span6
                h4 YouTube Videos  
                    .btn-group
                        button.btn.btn-small.btn-success(ng-click="new_video.adding = true") <i class="icon-plus"></i> New
                        button.btn.btn-small.btn-info(ng-show="listing_id>0", ng-click="saveVideoOrder()",ng-disabled="new_video.saving_sort") <i class="icon-save"></i> Save Order
                            i.icon-spinner.icon-spin(ng-show="new_video.saving_sort")
                ul.unstyled.video-list(ui-sortable, ng-model="formData.videos")
                    li(ng-repeat="v in formData.videos",style="position:relative;padding-left:16px")
                        span(style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;cursor:ns-resize") <i class="icon-resize-vertical"></i>
                        textarea(ng-model="v.code")
                        .btn-group
                            button.btn.btn-danger(ng-click="deleteVideo(v)", ng-disabled="new_video.deleting") <i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete
                                span(ng-show="new_video.deleting")
                                    i.icon-spinner.icon-spin
                            button.btn.btn-info(ng-click="new_video.preview_code=v.code") <i class="icon-eye-open"></i> Preview
                            button.btn.btn-primary(ng-click="v = updateVideo(v)", ng-disabled="v.updating") <i class="icon-save"></i> Update
                                i.icon-spinner.icon-spin(ng-show="v.updating")
            .span6(ng-show="new_video.preview_code")
                h4 Preview
                    a.btn.btn-danger.btn-mini(ng-click="new_video.preview_code = false")
                        i.icon-eye-close
                        |  Close
                div(ng-bind-html-unsafe="new_video.preview_code")
```

FYI: Most of the site is done.  Angular is used on the front end only for forms: Signup, Profile, Submit a Car, Messaging System & the Credit Application.  The admin is a complete angular app, but you'll have to get a job with the client to see that - and even then - I don't know! =)

Comment: Why do you ask the user to add the Youtube Embeded code instead of just the video url which you bind to an embeded code already on the page? Do you think it could make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce your bug, but I did this plunker in order to know if it does the same on your computer.

Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/LebJuOtlp6hOhzahQrIw?p=preview

In this demo, you must enter a youtube embeded video url like this (instead of the whole embeded code): http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id (To ease the user work, you could parse a regular youtube url to get the video id and change it to this form).

and click add to push it in the list. Then you click watch to set the selected item url in the iframe src.

Comment: So in IE9 on my site you don't have the issue???  I'm already working on changing it to your suggestion in your original comment... I'll just extract the video ID from the URL they type in and save that in the database, less to save, easier for the user... that was an excellent idea, and I'm not sure why I even went for the embed code to begin with... Still, if it turns out that it's only broken on my computer - wow.  Sucks to be me on my computer!

Comment: I'll try it once more, just in case!

Comment: I confirm that there is something wrong going on when I added more videos. I see many times (~100+) this message in the console: SCRIPT5009: « __flash__removeCallback » is undefined 
AG7ihOkT2YQ, Line 1 Caracter 1. I do not see this in Chrome.

Comment: I do not have the problem with the plunker and IE9 (or any). Maybe it comes from something else on your page.

Comment: Well, the only way to get my page to do it is to add an iframe with a width=560 or more. That said, I just finished updating my dev server here at home - just the one function of adding videos... I use a regex to grab the video id from any of the available youtube urls (the regular url, the share url and the embed code/url...) they could even paste the iframe in now... i just strip the id out and problem solved! no issues with IE9.  I will update my original question with URLs to the live site once it launches and leave the demo site alone for future reference. Thanks for your help!!